# Angular form values set parent to child form array pages

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

```
Parent HTML


<div formArrayName="pDFormArray">
          <div *ngFor="let pDForm of pDFormArray.controls; let j=index" [formGroupName]="j">
            <p-accordion #pAccordion class="pc-f-accordion">
              <p-accordionTab selected="true">

                <app-p-rotation [PRList]="PRList" #pDirection></app-p-rotation>

                <!-- </div> -->
              </p-accordionTab>
            </p-accordion>
          </div>
```

Parent Components have this pList list values.need to set this to child components array

```
[
```

{
      "dirC":"aa",
      "pList":[
         {
            "createdDt":"2018-11-09T13:39:04",
            "portStayDayQ":1,
            "portStayHrQ":1,
            "modifiedDt":"2018-11-09T13:39:05",
            "sailingHrQ":1,
            "terminalMu":"T1",
            "sailingDayQ":1,
         },
         {
            "createdDt":"2018-11-09T13:39:04",
            "portStayDayQ":2,
            "portStayHrQ":2,
            "modifiedDt":"2018-11-09T13:39:05",
            "sailingHrQ":2,
            "terminalMu":"T1",
            "sailingDayQ":2,
         },
         {
            "createdDt":"2018-11-09T13:39:04",
            "portStayDayQ":3,
            "portStayHrQ":3,
            "modifiedDt":"2018-11-09T13:39:05",
            "sailingHrQ":3,
            "terminalMu":"T1",
            "sailingDayQ":3,
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "dirC":"bbb",
      "pList":[
         {
            "createdDt":"2018-11-09T13:39:04",
            "portStayDayQ":1,
            "portStayHrQ":1,
            "modifiedDt":"2018-11-09T13:39:05",
            "sailingHrQ":1,
            "terminalMu":"T1",
            "sailingDayQ":1,
         },
         {
            "createdDt":"2018-11-09T13:39:04",
            "portStayDayQ":2,
            "portStayHrQ":2,
            "modifiedDt":"2018-11-09T13:39:05",
            "sailingHrQ":2,
            "terminalMu":"T1",
            "sailingDayQ":2,
            "seqN":2,
            "portC":"bb2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "dirC":"ccc",
      "pList":[
         {
            "createdDt":"2018-11-09T13:39:04",
            "portStayDayQ":1,
            "portStayHrQ":1,
            "modifiedDt":"2018-11-09T13:39:05",
            "sailingHrQ":1,
            "terminalMu":"T1",
            "sailingDayQ":1,
         },
         {
            "createdDt":"2018-11-09T13:39:04",
            "portStayDayQ":2,
            "portStayHrQ":2,
            "modifiedDt":"2018-11-09T13:39:05",
            "sailingHrQ":2,
            "terminalMu":"T1",
            "sailingDayQ":2,
         }
      ]
   }
]

Comment: `private` doesn't work out on `html` try to remove it and check - add some more details on your question

Comment: private remove does not work. I have updated question.please help

Comment: need to loop parant form array and need to call child component and set the values?

Comment: Can you please share your code - its difficult to understand your scenario - copy paste your code will try get solution from it

Comment: ok sure. I will update